# User is not allowed to perform this action

Tags: json, paypal, implicit

Our platform is trying to create a feature so that a seller can refund a paypal transaction after 60 days.  To do this our thought was that we would use the adaptive payment feature and simply ask paypal to send money from seller to buyer.

We created an application, and in the sandbox we have everything working.  When we move to production we get this response below.

{"errorId":"550001","domain":"PLATFORM","subdomain":"Application","severity":"Error","category":"Application","message":"User is not allowed to perform this action"}]}

The question is, "How does the seller authorize our platform?"  Do they need to check a box in their Paypal account?

What's a bit confusing to us, is that we are testing with our own 'seller' account which is of course a valid Paypal account.

Furthermore, we are doing a simple implicit approval.  We did notice that in our application registration we are 'conditionally excepted'.  We read that simple payments should work fine, it is only the chained payments that require specific approval from paypal.

Comment: Some code, ideally [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be useful.

Comment: can you post the complete response including correlation/debug id?